# R split out list based on name

Tags: r, list

Suppose I create the following structure

```
blah <- c()
for (i in 1:10) {
  blah <- c(blah,list(a=i,b=i+10))
}
```

I want `blah$a` to be a vector of `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` and `blah$b` to be a vector of `(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)`.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: `blah <- list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10+10)`

Comment: It needs to be parsed from a for loop -- this is just a simplified case.

Comment: I see... Look at my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work. I first split your list according to the names of elements and then "unlist" the list of list inside each list element. You can also `unname` each vector (not shown). See code:

```
lapply(split(x = blah, f = names(blah)), unlist)

$a
 a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 

$b
 b  b  b  b  b  b  b  b  b  b 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

In comments, @David mentions

```
split(unlist(blah), names(blah))
```

which also works and is probably more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. This does what I need.

Comment: You don't need a loop here, just `split(unlist(blah), names(blah))` should do

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can avoid loops:

```
blah <- list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10+10)
```

And you get this:

```
# > blah
# $a
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $b
# [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

# > blah$a
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

with loop:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  blah$a[i] <- i
  blah$b[i] <- i+10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 blah <- list()
 for (i in 1:10) {
   blah[['a']][i] <- i;  blah[['b']][i] <- i+10
   }

 blah
$a
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$b
 [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```